# Managing DLL dependencies with Maven

Tags: java, dll, maven-2, java-native-interface

I have a Java program with Maven managing its dependencies. One of those dependency is a JNI wrapper for another program. Maven takes care of the reference to the relevant JAR file, but I'm left messing around with the DLL file myself.

Is there a good way of having Maven handle the DLL as well? Ideally I would like to have the DLL loaded into our local repository like the JAR file.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Did you try something like this:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>footron</artifactId>
    <version>4.2</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <type>dll</type>
</dependency>
```

You can add them to maven's repository with something like this:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=footron.dll -DgroupId=com.foo -DartifactId=footron  -Dversion=4.2 -Dpackaging=dll -DgeneratePom=true
```

Haven't done this for DLLs but something like this should work.

Comment: Actually, after spending some additional time thinking about it I decided it was worth investing in the effort to remove the need for the DLL via JNI. Probably worth the effort in the long run. I will look into your suggestion though out of curiosity.

Comment: @Kris, that's probably a good idea. I thought of suggesting that but I don't make it a habit of telling people to fix code I haven't seen. AKA, Psychic code review

Comment: @sal, so does having maven manage the .dll file automatically call System.loadLibrary(<dll file>)? Or do you still have to call System.loadLibrary(<dll file>)? I'm just wondering how I make sure that dll is loaded for other objects to use.

Comment: I doubt it calls anything for you. The dll will be on the class path, but that's about it.

Comment: I'm unsure how -Dpackaging=dll can work, but it does.  When I try and make a real pom and use it it doesn't work however.

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution, which is described in the answer to this question: [Using maven with DLL from third party and managing the name of the DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50421441/using-maven-with-dll-from-third-party-and-managing-the-name-of-the-dll/50426244#50426244)

Basically, if you put the DLL into a ZIP file, and manage it as a separate dependency, and use the `nativedependencies-maven-plugin`, then the DLL will get unpacked with the right name.