# Maven Dll Dependency Problem

Tags: java, maven

I am developing a swing based desktop application and this application is using MediaInfo.dll library. I have first installed this dll to my local repository like described [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001774/managing-dll-dependencies-with-maven/1020101#1020101). Then I have added a dependency in my pom.xml like this

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mediainfo</groupId>
    <artifactId>mediainfo</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.44</version>    
    <type>dll</type>    
</dependency>
```

I am using Maven 3.0.3 version and when I executed mvn install assembly:assembly it says

> PlexusIoResourceCollection not found, no archiever found for dll

I am new to maven, so I am searching for a help before pulling my hear out .

Comment: Try adding a classifier tag before type for x86 or x64. So if you are on 32 bit environment, add <classifier>x86</classifier> before the type tag. If it works I'll post an answer below.

Comment: No I have tried but it doesn't work

Comment: Ok, will take a look at this more after work if no response prior to then.

Comment: Thanks. I will be waiting for your answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will depend on your assembly descriptor, but it seems like you have a `<dependencySet>` under which `<unpack>true</unpack>` is specified, that does not exclude the DLL from the set. Try adding this into that `dependencySet` element:

```
<excludes>
  <exclude>*:dll*</exclude>
</excludes>
```

If you intend to incorporate the DLL dependencies without unpacking them, then you might need an additional `dependencySet` element that includes them and doesn't specify the `unpack` flag. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html#class_dependencySet for more information.

Comment: For those not yet fluent in maven is it possible to given some context to where in the pom this 'excludes' XML belongs? What's the parent element? What's the parent of dependencySet? Is a minimal pom with this setup feasible to post?