# c++ from java application packaged in a jar file

Tags: java, c++, jar

I would like to call a c++ program from java application, packaged in a jar file. Is it possible to package and call c++ from the jar file?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Calling C++ functions from Java, you need read about [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface).

The exported C++ functions will store in dynamic libraries such as `.dll`(Windows) or `.so`(Linux) files.

Then try to package that `.dll` file into the jar file ([Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611357/how-to-make-a-jar-file-that-include-dll-files)).

Comment: Actually, you can package so's and dll's in JARs and Java can even load them with JNI! Here's some info on it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11578903/package-dll-in-jar-using-maven-single-goal

Comment: The C++ program is command line app with input + args and the generated output will be parsed by a java class. I want to deploy the c++ program packaged in a jar file with the java app.