# how to reference native DLL from Maven repo?

Tags: java, maven

If a JAR is accompanied with a native DLL in Maven repo what do I need to put into my pom.xml to get that DLL into the packaging?

To be more specific take for example [Jacob](http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cnet.sf.jacob-project%7Cjacob%7C1.14.3%7Cjar) library. How do you make `jacob-1.14.3-x64.dll` go into the `WEB-INF/lib` folder after you run `mvn package`?

In our local Nexus repository we've got these definitions for JAR and DLL:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.jacob-project</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacob</artifactId>
  <version>1.16-M2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.jacob-project</groupId>
  <artifactId>jacob</artifactId>
  <version>1.16-M2</version>
  <classifier>x64</classifier>
  <type>dll</type>
</dependency>
```

But putting the same dependencies to our project POM and running `mvn package` doesn't make DLL go to `WEB-INF/lib`, but JAR gets there fine.

What are we doing wrong?

Comment: PS I know that jacob 1.14 is outdated -- it's just for example

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001774/managing-dll-dependencies-with-maven) not answer the question?

Comment: How is the DLL stored in your repository?  Does it use a classifier of DLL with packaging of POM?

Comment: @eis unfortunately not - they decided to _remove the need for the DLL_ :)

Comment: @eis also, that question is about loading DLL into the repository, and I'm asking how to make that DLL go from the repository to the built project package (WAR for instance)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a DLL, you will need to use the [Copy Dependencies MOJO](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html).

You can filter out all dependencies other than the DLL and specify anywhere in your project structure to copy them to, including your target/webapp/WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: Great, thanks! Putting this mojo into `prepare-package` phase did the trick!

Comment: the other answer has the code, sorry I didn't notice that comment at that time

Answer (score 7):

Thanks to the hint from Monty0018 I was able to solve the problem. The maven code that works for me:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <id>copy-dependencies</id>
          <phase>prepare-package</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
          </goals>
          <configuration>
            <excludeTransitive>true</excludeTransitive>
            <includeArtifactIds>jacob</includeArtifactIds>
            <failOnMissingClassifierArtifact>true</failOnMissingClassifierArtifact>
            <silent>false</silent>
            <outputDirectory>target/APPNAME/WEB-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
            <overWriteReleases>true</overWriteReleases>
            <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
            <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
          </configuration>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
```

Comment: Can you tell me one thing: How does it work your solution ? Must you modify path of libararies during starting ? Must you do something else thatn modyfiying pom.xml ?