# Dll files in maven pom

Tags: java, maven, dll, openshift

i've java maven project and i'm using opencv api in it. I've to set up enviromental path to dlls, which are necessary to run my project locally. Now i want to install my app on openshift's tomcat 7 and i need to export those dlls somehow with my war. For now i get unsatisfied link error.

i tried to put dlls as a dependencies to pom file and add dll to maven local repository, but with no luck. I used this commands:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=filedll -DgroupId=com.file -DartifactId=file  -Dversion=2.45 -Dpackaging=dll -DgeneratePom=true

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.file</groupId>
    <artifactId>file</artifactId>
    <version>2.45</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
    <type>dll</type>
</dependency>
```

When i try to build war i get following error:

> remote: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project service: Could not resolve dependencies for project pl.test:service:war:1.0: Could not find artifact com.file:file:dll:2.45 in eap (http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all) ->
>    [Help 1]

Maybe i should set  in pom file?

I'm open to all your ideas :)
Thanks,
Wojtek

Comment: What is the output from `mvn install:install-file ...` ? Any perhaps it should be `-Dfile=file.dll` ? Have you tried the `-X` switch?

Comment: @GyroGearless i'm not able to put here output from mavens install, but everything goes fine and dependency is created in .m2 repo. -Dfile was just a mistake, whene i wrote this post.

Comment: In another question, this issue is solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8873704/how-to-reference-native-dll-from-maven-repo