# Maven custom dependency types

Tags: java, maven, types, dependencies

Lets say I have my own java bootstrap framework written in Perl. Lets say there are different versions of it, upon which different Java projects depend.

Is there anyway to add such a thing as a dependency in maven and have be treated as a... custom dependency type?

I'm running maven from an ant build script.

(So basically just using maven for dependency management.)

Example:

```
javaprojectroot/

  lib/

  bin/

  perllib/
```

Where perllib is a special kind of dependency also managed by maven...

Comment: Is there a specific question? Have you tried anything or just asking in general? What do you want to achieve by having the dependency managed by maven? Package it? Use it from your java code?

Comment: I want to be able to package and compile using maven managed dependencies.

Comment: However, some of those dependencies might be perllibs, which won't be needed at compile time, but will be required at package time...

Comment: Ok, an you want to build what? A war? Jar? Or just a bunch of files? :)

Comment: Suppose you wanted to include a custom ant build file, the type would be 'xml'.  In our case we want a type like 'bin'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [install these libs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/install-file-mojo.html) in your maven repository. You can specify any type of packaging you want, for example `zip` or `dll`. Then you can reference these libs as a normal dependency. You should have a look at the [documentation of the assembly-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/), so you can create a correct package with those kinds of dependencies.

Comment: Nice. That could work. Didn't know if it was as simple as installing... What type of packaging do u think I should specify?

Comment: @Nik You mean the packaging of the lib, aren't you? I would use the file ending of the lib. We used that for a `dll` and it worked fine.

Comment: Similar idea, incase anyone stumbles on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001774/managing-dll-dependencies-with-maven