# DLL Files for Maven

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have a 3rd party jar file that requires a .dll to run.

Referring to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001774/managing-dll-dependencies-with-maven), I have successfully placed both my 3rd party jar files and the dll files into my person repo at .m2.

I'm am still getting errors:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'libtesseract302': The specified module could not be found.
```

Do i have to specify a build path in maven to ensure that dll files work?

Or is there a way to build the jar file together with the DLL file to prevent this error?

Comment: SOLVED:

I loaded the dll through the method mentioned here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611357/how-to-make-a-jar-file-that-include-dll-files?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting means the dll cannot be found in the `java.library.path`.

Unfortunately You cannot load DLL from the JAR directly. You can package it within the JAR and unpack it before loading it. Checkout the question [Extract and load DLL from JAR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764347/extract-and-load-dll-from-jar).

Comment: Thanks! You pointed me in the right direction. I refered to this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1611357/how-to-make-a-jar-file-that-include-dll-files?rq=1) in the end.