# Build jar using maven with native .so

Tags: java, maven, jar, native

I have *.so library and want to pack project into jar. Can someone help with problem how to force maven to pack native libraries so when i run jar they can be used?

i don`t want to add .so as new artifact. It is build also with maven before i build main java project so i just want to pack them into jar so i can use it.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Managing DLL dependencies with Maven](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001774/managing-dll-dependencies-with-maven)

Comment: Copy resources with maven: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/copy-resources.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've copied resources before but couldn't read .so which was within the jar. So finally I've found [Load library from jar](http://adamheinrich.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-load-native-jni-library-from-jar/) and achieved my goal.