# How to connect a dll file in maven project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, dll, pom.xml

I'm trying to convert existing intellij idea project to maven project and I am having difficulty with connecting a dll library jaybird22_x64.dll which uses the library jaybird-jdk17. Here is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>test</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>InstatUpdateService</name>
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.firebirdsql.jdbc</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaybird-jdk17</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Can someone help.. how correctly write a block dependency to connect dll library?

Comment: Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001774/managing-dll-dependencies-with-maven?

Comment: Yes, I tried to add dependency in pom file and via the command line - not working..