# Using maven with DLL from third party and managing the name of the DLL

Tags: java, maven, dll, native

I have a maven project and am using the `nativedependencies-maven-plugin` (https://github.com/fmarot/nativedependencies-maven) to manage the DLL.

The DLL is from a third party, and has the following structure.  Let's say that the name of the JAR file is `abc.jar` and the corresponding DLL is `abcxyz.dll`, where xyz is the version number without periods.  So if the version is 12.6.1, the DLL is named `abc1261.dll`.  If the third party updates their product to version 12.7.0, they issue a new JAR `abc.jar` and a new DLL `abc1270.dll`.

I am storing the JAR in a local repository, and the name of the JAR as reflected in the repository is then `abc-x.y.z.jar`.  I put a classifier on the DLL called `natives-abc`, and the name of the DLL in the repository (once deployed) is `abc-x.y.z-natives-abc.dll`.  When I build the project, `abc-x.y.z-natives-abc.dll` is then properly copied over to the `target/natives` folder by the `nativedependencies-maven-plugin`.

When I run the project from Eclipse, it fails, because the JAR is looking for `abcxyz.dll` and not `abc-x.y.z-natives-abc.dll`.  If I copy `abc-x.y.z-natives-abc.dll` into `abcxyz.dll` in the `target/natives` folder, then everything works, so I know that the `java.library.path` is getting set correctly, which I have also verified by inspecting the process using the `jinfo` tool.

What I need is for the DLL to get renamed once it is copied from the local repository into `target/natives`.  I can't figure out how to make maven do that.

What I want to do is have different versions of `abc.jar` and `abcxyz.dll` in the local repository, and then just change the `<version>` tags in the `pom.xml` file to refer to different versions.  The name of the JAR file in deployment isn't relevant, but it's associated DLL name is relevant because the JAR file from the third party for a specific version looks for a specific DLL name corresponding to the version.

Answer (score 2):

Maintainer of `nativedependencies-maven-plugin` here.

I'm not sure I understand completely but I think I have a solution:
if you were to deploy/install in you repo (local or not) the .jar (not the .dll) provided by your 3<sup>rd</sup> party, then when Maven will get this dependency and unzip it (with the `nativedependency-maven-plugin`), it will keep untouched the name of the `.dll` inside it. So your code (or the 3rd party code) will correctly find it at runtime.

If your own code loads the DLL, I'd have suggested to rename the DLL to a unique name without the version to simplify the process. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The above suggestion worked.  What I had to do was create a `zip` containing `abcxyz.dll`, (calling it `abcxyz.dll.zip`), add that to the maven repository using `zip` packaging, and then make the dependency in `pom.xml` refer to that.

In other words, here is the section of the `pom.xml` that had the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thegroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
    <version>12.6.1</version>
    <type>zip</type>
    <classifier>natives-abc</classifier>
</dependency>
```

I just used WinZip to create the Zip.

```
mvn deploy:deploy-file -Durl=file:///path-to-my-repo -Dfile=abc1261.dll.zip -DgroupId=com.thegroup -DartifactId=abc -Dpackaging=zip -Dversion=12.6.1 -Dclassifier=natives-abc
```