# How to add an external .dll on JavaFX native library

Tags: java, javafx, java-native-interface, native

I would like help in understanding how I can add an external DLL to my native .exe compilation using `com.zenjava`. The problem is that I need `win32com.dll` as one of my dependencies to run my project.

I've tried this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001774/managing-dll-dependencies-with-maven) but it didn't work for me.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=../../artefatos/Java Communication API/win32com.dll -DgroupId=win32com.dll -DartifactId=dll -Dversion=2.0.3 -Dpackaging=dll -DgeneratePom=true
```

The error that occurs is as follows:

> Error installing artifact 'win32com:dll:dll': Failed to install
>   artifact win32com:dll:dll:2:
>   D:\Projects\sentusdesk-project\desktop\sentusdesk (Acesso negado)

Is there any way to add this DLL to my app's native release?

My pom.xml:

```
    <build>
        <finalName>SentusDesk</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <bootclasspath>${sun.boot.class.path}${path.separator}${java.home}/lib/jfxswt.jar</bootclasspath>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>8.8.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <vendor>Datachamp</vendor>
                    <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
                    <verbose>true</verbose>
                    <bundler>EXE</bundler>
                    <nativeReleaseVersion>${project.version}</nativeReleaseVersion>
                    <permissions>
                        <permission>all-permissions</permission>
                    </permissions>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-jfxjar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>create-native</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-native</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

My .iss file:

```
;This file will be executed next to the application bundle image
;I.e. current directory will contain folder SentusDesk with application files
[Setup]
AppId={{br.com.sentus.desk}}
AppName=SentusDesk
AppVersion=1.2.18
AppVerName=SentusDesk 1.2.18
AppPublisher=Datachamp
AppComments=SentusDesk
DefaultDirName={pf32}\SentusDesk
DisableStartupPrompt=Yes
DisableDirPage=No
DisableProgramGroupPage=Yes
DisableReadyPage=Yes
DisableFinishedPage=No
DisableWelcomePage=No
DefaultGroupName=Datachamp
OutputBaseFilename=SentusDesk
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
PrivilegesRequired=poweruser
SetupIconFile=SentusDesk\SentusDesk.ico
UninstallDisplayIcon={app}\SentusDesk.ico
UninstallDisplayName=UninstallSentusDesk
WizardImageStretch=No

[Languages]
Name: brazilianportuguese; MessagesFile: compiler:Languages\BrazilianPortuguese.isl

[Dirs]
Name: "{app}";
Name: "{app}\app";
Name: "{app}\app\config"; Permissions: everyone-full

[Files]
Source: "SentusDesk\SentusDesk.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "SentusDesk\*"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
Source: "SentusDesk\app\*"; DestDir: "{app}\app\"; Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs;
Source: "SentusDesk\app\config\*"; DestDir: "{app}\app\config\"; Flags: skipifsourcedoesntexist ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs; Permissions: everyone-full

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\SentusDesk"; Filename: "{app}\SentusDesk.exe"; IconFilename: "{app}\SentusDesk.ico"; Check: returnTrue()
Name: "{commondesktop}\SentusDesk"; Filename: "{app}\SentusDesk.exe";  IconFilename: "{app}\SentusDesk.ico"; Check: returnFalse()
Name: "{userdesktop}\SentusDesk"; Filename: "{app}\SentusDesk.exe";  IconFilename: "{app}\SentusDesk.ico"; Parameters: "SentusDesk.exe"; Comment: "Sentus Desk";


[Run]
Filename: "{app}\SentusDesk.exe"; Parameters: "-Xappcds:generatecache"; Check: returnFalse()
Filename: "{app}\SentusDesk.exe"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,SentusDesk}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent; Check: returnTrue()
Filename: "{app}\SentusDesk.exe"; Parameters: "-install -svcName ""SentusDesk"" -svcDesc ""SentusDesk"" -mainExe ""SentusDesk.exe""  "; Check: returnFalse()

[UninstallRun]
Filename: "{app}\UninstallSentusDesk.exe "; Parameters: "-uninstall -svcName UninstallSentusDesk -stopOnUninstall"; Check: returnFalse()

[Code]
function returnTrue(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
end;

function returnFalse(): Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
end;

function InitializeSetup(): Boolean;
begin
// Possible future improvements:
//   if version less or same => just launch app
//   if upgrade => check if same app is running and wait for it to exit
//   Add pack200/unpack200 support? 
  Result := True;
end;
```

Comment: I think you are confusing something. `install:install-file` manually installs an artifact in locally maven repositories. what exe are you really talking about? executable application or installer?

Comment: So, I'm generating an installer, and inside him I need to put this DLL because when the user will install, the program needs it.

Comment: Once you have the configuration for *inno setup* (iss file), I just add a library entry (for example `Source: "<path_to_dll>\win32com.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion`). Another option is to use maven to copy *win32com.dll* to directory *SentusDesk*. So *inno setup* will automatically include it in the installation.

Comment: @mrmcwolf I'll try, thanks

Comment: @mrmcwolf I've used your example, and it works, thanks.